# Can i get a appropriate regular expression for the following string in java with the following condition

Tags: java, regex

The test String is

```
It is a test data
%Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single
 host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this
 interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.
 Use with CAUTION
Test is a test.
```

The string is invalid if the string has `%` symbol in it. But it is valid if the `%` is followed with the following sequence of characters, "%Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single\n host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this\n interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.\n Use with CAUTION".Even in this case the '%' symbol can be present only once.

My code is:

```
public class Abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String reg="%(Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single\n host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this\n interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.\n Use with CAUTION)([^%])";
        String str = "%Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single\n host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this\n interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.\n Use with CAUTIONTest is a testData is invalid%";
        Pattern regEx2 = Pattern
                .compile(reg);
        Matcher matcher = regEx2.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not getting what is expected.
Can I get a suitable regular expression?

Comment: At what DO you expect? Seems to work for me: https://ideone.com/Q2y21b

Comment: if the string has another '%' at the end it still throws valid. String str = "%Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single\n host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this\n interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.\n Use with CAUTIONTest is a testData is invalid%";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could combile your code with another expression that gets the count of '%'

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     String reg = "%Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single\n host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this\n interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.\n Use with CAUTION";
     String str = "%Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single\n host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this\n interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.\n Use with CAUTIONTest is a testData is invalid%";
     Pattern regEx2 = Pattern.compile(reg);
     Matcher matcher = regEx2.matcher(str);
     int occurences = str.length() - str.replace("%", "").length();

     if (matcher.find() && occurences <= 1) {
        System.out.println("valid");
     } else {
        System.out.println("invalid");
     }

 }
```

If you have StringUtils class then you can use its method **countMatches**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are 2 problems in your code:

1. `find` method only tries to find an occurrence of the given pattern in the string. In your case you need to use `matches`, which checks if full string matches the pattern.
2. `([^%])` - this only matches ONE character that is not a `%`. To match any amount of characters use `([^%]*)`. `*` means "0 or more", or you could need `+` instead which means "1 or more".

So the resulting code looks like this: https://ideone.com/Q2y21b

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String reg="%(Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single\n host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this\n interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.\n Use with CAUTION)([^%]+)";
    String str = "%Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single\n host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this\n interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.\n Use with CAUTIONTest is a testData is invalid%";
    Pattern regEx2 = Pattern
            .compile(reg);
    Matcher matcher = regEx2.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: this works fine for more than one '%' symbol but still fails if we add any characters before the %symbol in the string like String str = "AA%Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single\n host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc. to this\n interface when portfast is enabled can cause temporary bridging loops.\n Use with CAUTIONTest is a testData is invalid%";

Comment: Well, add `[^%]+` in the beginning for that.